# WCF endpoint not found/method not allowed using Windows Service

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I want to host my WCF web service on windows service so the front end can access the methods.

The service runs fine if I clicked on the service(view in Browser) in VS. But when I tired to host it using Windows Service, it's returning "Endpoint not found" from the browser when I used the base address and "Method Not Allow" When I specific the method that I want to access.

Below is my code:
Host's App.Config:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
 </startup>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
     <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="BestWebService.Service1">
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
        contract="BestWebService.IService1" 
        bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
   </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="jsonBinding">
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     </security>
    </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service.cs

```js
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (host != null) {
                host.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BestWebService.Service1));
                host.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                string stored = @"c:\\SETUP ERROR.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(stored))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("1: {0}", e.ToString());
                }
                host.Close();
            }
        }
```

WCF Service Interface

```js
public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        List<WKSTEnviornment> GetWKSTDetails();
    }
```

Javascript

```js
getAllVersions = function (id) {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetWKSTDetails',
  method: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
   var verlist = new Array();
   var appname = new Array();
   var applications = new Array();
   var name = null;
   var Object = {};
   $.each(data.d, function (i) {
    var apps = data.d[i]["AppList"].split('_');
    verlist.push(data.d[i]["Version"]);
    $.each(apps, function (i) {
     appname.push(apps[i]);
    })
    appname.sort();
    var ver = data.d[i]["Version"];
    Object[ver] = { Date: data.d[i]["Date"], Applist: appname };
    appname = [];
   });
   versionlist = Object;
   getversion = true;
   createDeployPanel(Object, verlist, id);
  },
  error: function (data) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data) + 'Get Versions Failed');
  }
 });
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Z  IService1 is not decorated with [ServiceContract] attribute..Can you check it?

Comment: It is, I forgot to included the line

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the issue with Windows Service (the service is hosted successfully tho) so I switched it to IIS(config and CORS also took me some time to resolved), now it's working :)